# What does 'bad cold' refer into this situation?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrases, grammaticality-in-context, british-english

‘They didn’ keep their gold in the house, boy! Nah, first stop fer us is Gringotts.Wizards’ bank. Have a sausage, they’re not bad cold – an’ I wouldn’ say no teh a bit o’ yer birthday cake, neither.’
‘Wizards have banks?’
‘Just the one. Gringotts. Run by goblins.’
Harry dropped the bit of sausage he was holding.
‘Goblins?’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally eat sausages when they are hot. The speaker is saying

> ... they are [not bad](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-bad) [when they are] cold.